# AWS - API Gateway to SQS with full request as body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

I created an API Gateway of protocol `HTTP` to act as an API Gateway for webhook for some service. The service sends a signature in some header, as well as some information in the body. I want my gateway to pass the whole request object (headers + body) as the body of the SQS message but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

I created a new integration and chose `SQS.SendMessage`. I put in the SQS URL and the invocation role and for the message body I put: `$request.body.MessageBody`. However, I'm not sure how to include that special header (or the whole request as a whole).

Comment: Have you checked CloudWatch for errors related to the `Bad Request`?

Comment: @Salkz I don't see any logs of my API Gateway there.